# Is there any reason for instantiating MatDialogConfig via "new"?

Tags: angular, angular-material

In the context of using `MatDialog`, what is the difference between these two options?

Option A:

```js
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
dialogConfig.width = "320px";
dialogConfig.height = "200px";
// ... other properties
this.dialog.open(MyDialog, dialogConfig);
```

Option B:

```js
const dialogConfig = {
  width = "320px";
  height = "200px";
  // ... other properties
}
this.dialog.open(MyDialog, dialogConfig);
```

Which one is preferrable and why? Is the `MatDialogConfig` prototype really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/dialog/dialog-config.ts), you'll realize all the class does is setting default values to some of it's members. It doesn't have initialization logic nor methods.

Besides that, in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview), the configuration is always passed as a regular JavaScript object rather than an instance of `MatDialogConfig`.

An example taken from the docs:

```js
let dialogRef = dialog.open(UserProfileComponent, {
  height: '400px',
  width: '600px',
});
```

So I'd say one should stick to that, since it's simpler and it's what the authors suggest in documentation.